# How to associate class predictions with scores values of f1_score

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have multi class classification task, I'd like to estimate the prediction results for every class. For this I use
`f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average = None)`.
It is Ok, I receive corresponding scores. But what I cannot understand - how to associate results with predicted classes. For example I have the following train and test data sets:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'c1' : [1,2,3,4], 'c2' : [1,2,3,4], 'y_true' : ['a','b','c','d]})

test  = pd.DataFrame({'c1' : [11,21,31,41], 'c2' : [11,21,31,41]})
```

After prediction pipeline I have for example the following results:

```
y_pred = ['a', 'd', 'a', 'c']
```

and f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average = None) something like this:

```
scores = array([0.8, 0.3, 0.99])
```

The question is how I associate values from scores with class labels ['a','b','c','d]?

Answer (score 0):

You can zip your two lists together and access them like this in a for-loop.

```py
for cls, f1 in zip(y_pred, scores):
    print(f"Class: {cls}, F1: {f1}")
```

If you want to access them as a dictionary you can wrap the zip with a dict() constructor like this

```py
score_dict = dict(zip(y_pred, scores))
```

Comment: I cannot agree. I have 4 rows for predictions and only 3 values for scores. It seems to me that scores correspond to predicted classes not for  rows in test dataset

Comment: In sklearn.metrics.f1_score you can also send the labels as a parameter is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I have made some tests with labels - but either I use it wrong or labels are used for other aims. I have received not I whant

Answer (score 0):

You can use the labels argument. This will be used as the order in which you want your F1 scores to be output. If you don't provide this, f1_score will return the labels in the order it encounters them in your `y_pred` and `y_true`

```py
f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None, labels=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

> The set of labels to include when average != 'binary', and their order if average is None. Labels present in the data can be excluded, for example to calculate a multiclass average ignoring a majority negative class, while labels not present in the data will result in 0 components in a macro average. For multilabel targets, labels are column indices. By default, all labels in y_true and y_pred are used in sorted order. [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html)